# Having issues updating a column in my db using a SPROC

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This stored procedure doesn't update the column FailedLoginAttempts if the conditions are true. Can anyone tell me what might be wrong with this?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE UpdateFailedLoginAttempts
    (
        @username varchar(100),
        @failureType varchar(100),
        @maxInvalidPasswordAttempts int
    )
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @failureCount int

    IF (@failureType='Password') BEGIN
        SELECT @failureCount=FailedLoginAttempts FROM Users
        WHERE Username=@username

        UPDATE Users SET FailedLoginAttempts=@failureCount+1 WHERE Username=@username    

        IF(@failureCount >= @maxInvalidPasswordAttempts) BEGIN
            UPDATE Users SET IsUserLocked = 1 WHERE Username=@username
        END 
    END
END
```

What i'm trying to achieve is if the `failureType` is *Password*, then it should SET `@failureCount` equal to `FailedLoginAttempts` and then update `FailedLoginAttempts` to `@failureCount + 1` (to increase the amount of failed attempts) and then check if `@failureCount` is greater than or equal to `@maxInvalidPasswordAttempts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I am noticing is that you:

- set `@failureCount = FailedLoginAttempts`
- update `FailedLoginAttempts = @failureCount + 1`
- check `@failureCount >= @maxInvalidPasswordAttempts`

This is not checking against the updated FailedLoginAttempts value, so you will likely have to fail one additional time than you expect before an account is locked.

Since you have to run an update anyway, you could consider this route:

```
UPDATE u
SET u.IsUserLocked =
   CASE
      WHEN (FailedLoginAttempts + 1) >= @maxInvalidPasswordAttempts THEN 1
      ELSE u.IsUserLocked
   END
   , u.FailedLoginAttempts = u.FailedLoginAttempts + 1
FROM Users AS u
WHERE u.Username = @username
```

It removes the need to make multiple statements, or the variable `@failureCount`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. But for now my focus is on getting it to actually update the FailedLoginAttempts column. Do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: both your code in the `IF` (as well as mine) works. (testing on sql-server-2012-CTP3)  My best guess is that your `@failureType` is NOT 'Password', or you do not have a person with the `@userName` specified.

Comment: Can you run this with a test user calling the sproc yourself and post those results?  If you can test in `SSMS` on a dev server, you can also put a `PRINT` inside the `IF` to ensure you're getting inside the IF block.

Comment: You were right. The @failureType if statement was the one ruining this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if your column `FailedLoginAttempts` has a default value of 0 and not null?